# Share authentication information between two android apps

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-keystore, data-sharing

I know this question has been asked before but I still looking for better answers as not convinced with other solutions.

My use case is - I want to share the authentication information between two different mobile apps. Basically, if a user is successfully logged in into one app, and then if the user open another app, the user should be logged in.

Did research and found Content Provider to be the solution.

I did POC on the same and found it very useful. But with content provider, it is preferable to use the `android:protectionLevel` attribute set to `signature` protection so that only the app signed using the same key can query the data from content provider. In my case, the apps are `not signed using the same key`. Without this, I find content provider to be less helpful because I need to share the authentication information and security is the topmost priority. If I've over looked anything over here, please highlight.

What I can do on top of it is - I can store the data in content provider by encrypting and decrypting in the other app. Then the next challenge that comes is, how can I securely save the encryption/decryption keys in the android application itself? Should I share it in the CPP files from which it is harder to get the information?

Is there any other secure way to make the data information available in other apps?

PS: This question is like a problem solving question where I am seeking guidance that's why didn't post any code over here. That would have been redundant.

Comment: you can save SHA-1  encrypted data in app 1 SharedPrefrence and share it to app 2 and decrypt it there. if you want a demo on it let me know.

Comment: Even in this case, how will I store the encryption keys securely in both apps? A demo!! Yes please. that would be helpful. @ShivanshuVerma

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service with AIDL to communicate between apps:

> The Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) is similar to other
> IDLs: it lets you define the programming interface that both the
> client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other
> using interprocess communication (IPC).

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

You may also need to define a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```